# Is there a sequence with no convergent subsequence but small distances between terms?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples

Is there a metric space $(X, d)$ and a sequence $(x_{n})$ in $X$ that has no convergent subsequence but infimum of the set of distance between elements of the set is zero?

To be more precise, $\inf\{d(x_{m},x_{n}) | n,m\in N,\,m\ne n\} = 0$

Comment: Have a look at $x_n = \log(n)$ in the standard metric of R.

Comment: Isn't $1,1,2,3,4,5,\dots$ a counterexample? The infimum of the set of distances is $d(x_1,x_2)$ which is equal to $0.$

Comment: Another counterexample: $1,1.1,2,2.01,3,3.001,4,4.0001,\dots$

Comment: @bof i edit that mistake

Comment: @bof what if we take each element separately? for example take 1.1. which is a singleton set and subsequence of your counterexample. and its converge itself. the point i wonder is this actually. thank you

Comment: I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: i mean if we construct a subsequence with one element , which converge itself in that subsequence , that constuction violates our constraint that X has no convergent subsequence.

Comment: @Johndresden One element does not make a subsequence, right? You need infinitely many elements to make a subsequence. It is possible that all of them are the same, in which case you have a constant subsequence, which you are referring to. To  construct a subsequence of a sequence, you cannot take one element out and call it a subsequence: you need infinitely many elements, one after the other. That, I think,is the catch.

Comment: I think you have kind of put your question wrongly. I think you want, that there should be many, many elements whose difference keeps getting smaller and smaller, right? Tell me if I am right, because somewhere I feel we have not perceived the question the way you have asked it.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг than you for information about subsequence. i think you understand the problem, and also ,from your explanation,  1,1.1,2,2.01,3,3.001,4,4.0001 is a good example for sequence in R with usual metric?

Comment: I think you actually want the [limit inferior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior) of the sequence to be zero, if you're not satisfied with bof's counterexample.

Comment: @Johndresden Exactly. I think this is a good example of what you want, the "liminf", as it is called, must be zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ be the real subspace $\{\log n: n\in \mathbb N\}$ with the usual metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|.$  Since $0<\log (n+1)-\log n=\log (1+1/n)<1/n$ we have $\inf \{d(x,y):x\ne y\}=0$. But $X$ is a discrete space.

Or let $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ be any other strictly increasing real sequence with $\lim_{n\to \infty}(x_{n+1}-x_n)=0$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=\infty.$ And let $X=\{x_n:n\in \mathbb N\}$ with $d(x,y)=|x-y|.$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\Bbb Q$ with the standard metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ and let $\displaystyle (s_n)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n^2}$. Then $s_n \to \dfrac{\pi^2}{6} \notin \Bbb Q$ and therefore:

(i) $(s_n)$ is Cauchy implies $\inf\{d(s_m,s_n): m, n\in \Bbb N\}=0$

(ii) every subsequence of $(s_n)$ converges to $\frac{\pi^2}{6} \notin \Bbb Q$.

Comment: If you're going to use a non-complete example, it's simpler to just take something like $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ and $x_n = 1/n$ IMO.

Comment: I've tried to be exotic. Thanks for your simpler example